# Не возможно запустить контейнер, завершенный некорректно

Tags: linux, docker, восстановление, recovery

Стоит докер вот такой версии.

```
docker-compose version 1.19.0
Docker version 18.02.0-ce, build fc4de447b5
```

Запускаю проект, работаю с ним, потом как бац и нет электричества, фриз иксов, села батарейка и т.д. Пробую запустить обратно, а там как

```
% docker-compose up radius                                                                         
compose_postgres_1 is up-to-date
Starting compose_radius_1 ... error

ERROR: for compose_radius_1  Cannot start service radius: container "264eb2b171e461fe7d4239baf813e7e584f8818f9d6073dee4bbd517d66424f7": already exists

ERROR: for radius  Cannot start service radius: container "264eb2b171e461fe7d4239baf813e7e584f8818f9d6073dee4bbd517d66424f7": already exists
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Естественно контейнер этот не запущен, `ps` смотрел, остановить пробовал - ничего не помогает кроме как очистка файловой системы контейнера и сборка его с новым uuid.

Как сказать докеру что он не прав? Где лежит этот lock-файл? Может запись в db?

Comment: `docker-compose down` пробовали?

Comment: @FCh да, пробовал. но с именем контейнера. down без имени помог

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стоит сделать `docker-compose down`. Можно с опцией `-t 1`, чтобы не ждать таймаута.
Эта команда останавливает контейнеры и удаляет контейнеры, сети, тома (ваш случай) и образы, созданные через `docker-compose up`. [Документация по docker-compose down](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/)

Команда `docker-compose down radius` не удаляет потому что оставались висеть зависимые `run`.

```
 % docker-compose down
Stopping compose_postgres_1 ... done
Removing compose_radius_1      ... done
Removing compose_radius_run_10 ... done
Removing compose_radius_run_9  ... done
Removing compose_radius_run_8  ... done
Removing compose_radius_run_7  ... done
Removing compose_radius_run_6  ... done
Removing compose_radius_run_5  ... done
Removing compose_radius_run_4  ... done
Removing compose_radius_run_3  ... done
Removing compose_radius_run_2  ... done
Removing compose_radius_run_1  ... done
Removing compose_postgres_1    ... done
Removing network compose_default
```